# How to group identical values from a list into their own lists?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say I have a list `[2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]`

I would like to produce lists that contain identical values from the list above.

Expected Output something like:

```
[2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[7, 7]
[8]
```

The order that these lists are produced doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you working with numbers, or strings? Also, what do you need this for... can you give us more details?

Comment: Numbers (Integers to be precise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
l = [2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]
for i in set(l):
   print([i]*l.count(i))
```

Output:

```
[8]
[2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[7, 7]
```

Comment: `[[i]*l.count(if) for i in set(l)]`

Comment: There is a "problem" with this solution. It will iterate on l several times. It is not a problem for small lists. But will get slower for big ones. The `O(n)` solution with defaultdict will perform much faster.

Answer (score 5):

Best approach is an `O(n)` solution with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> l = [2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for e in l:
...     d[e].append(e)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3, 3], 7: [7, 7], 8: [8]})
>>> d.values()
dict_values([[2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [7, 7], [8]])
```

Alternatively you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with sorted list:

```
>>> for _, l in itertools.groupby(sorted(l)):
...     print(list(l))
... 
[2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[7, 7]
[8]
```

Or a list comprehension with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [[i]*n for i,n in Counter(l).items()]
[[2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [7, 7], [8]]
```

As I post, the defaultdict solution is `O(n)` and faster than the other aproaches. Here are the tests:

```
from timeit import timeit


setup = (
"from collections import Counter, defaultdict;"
"from itertools import groupby;"
"l = [2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3];"
)

defaultdict_call = (
"d = defaultdict(list); "
"\nfor e in l: d[e].append(e);"
)
groupby_call = "[list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l))]"
counter_call = "[[i]*n for i,n in Counter(l).items()]"


for call in (defaultdict_call, groupby_call, counter_call):
  print(call)
  print(timeit(call, setup))
```

Results:

```
d = defaultdict(list); 
for e in l: d[e].append(e);
7.02662614302244
[list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l))]
10.126392606005538
[[i]*n for i,n in Counter(l).items()]
19.55539561196929
```

Here is the [live test](https://repl.it/repls/FixedSafeInitializationfile)

Comment: Let me fix that @Aran-Fey

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short way of doing it by using `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
my_dict = Counter([2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]) # returns {3: 3, 2: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1}

new_list = [[k] * v for k,v in my_dict.items()]
```

Outputs:

```
[[2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [7, 7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use a simple [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
l = [2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]

groups = {}
for n in l:
    groups.setdefault(n, []).append(n)

print(list(groups.values()))
# [[2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [7, 7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing this operation in Numpy array would be efficient

```
a= np.array([2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3])
[a[a==i] for i in np.unique(a)]
```

Output:

```
[array([2, 2]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([7, 7]), array([8])]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may try collections.Counter, and get different keys and its count in this list.

```
from collections import Counter
l = [2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]
c =Counter(l)
print(c) ## result: {3: 3, 2: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is with ***list-comprehension***:

```
l = [2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]

print(*[[i]*l.count(i) for i in set(l)], sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
[8]
[2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[7, 7]
```

Moreover, the output can be made exactly as yours with `sorted()` method

```
l = [2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]

print(*sorted([[i]*l.count(i) for i in set(l)]), sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
[2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[7, 7]
[8]
```

**EDIT :** As the answer gets upvoted I want to explain the code in detail to be helpful as much as I can.

The code is this:

```
 print(*[[i]*l.count(i) for i in set(l)], sep='\n')
```

Using `set(l)` eliminates duplicated values and remains only `[2, 3, 7, 8]` in the list. Later,  in `[i]` we put each element of `set(l)` in a new list. We count how many time `i` element(`i` is a element in `set(l`)) occurs in native list `l` (`l = [2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 3]`). And in `[i]*l.count(i)` `i` become `l.count(i)` times in the new list. List-comprehension method gets the all values after iterations are done and pack it in a list and returns list. `*` sign at the beginning is for unpacking the values in the returned list. And finally `*print()*` keyword `sep='\n'` put a `'\n'` after each elements in the unpacked list. Without it this could have been done like:

```
for j in [[i]*l.count(i) for i in set(l)]:
    print(j)
```